# parse error in php for the statement syntax, missing something

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to echo the value of the field form the database in the drop-down list retrieved from another table in the database, but I keep getting the Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

I know i am m missing something in the brackets to comma, but I can't seem to see it,

```
 <?php
      $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `CompanyID`, `Name` FROM `company`") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
           foreach($row1 AS $key1 => $value1) {
                $row1[$key1] = stripslashes($value1);
           } 

           echo "<option value=" . nl2br( $row1['CompanyID']) . " ". if($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant) echo 'selected = "selected"'
        . ">" . nl2br( $row1['Name']) . "</option>";
        } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `if` like you did in your code (in a string). It returns nothing. Use this:

```
$sValue = boolean_value ? 'value if TRUE' : 'value if FALSE';
```

It's called a "Ternary Operator". PHP docs link:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Change it like this, for example:

```
 <?php
      $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `CompanyID`, `Name` FROM `company`") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
           foreach($row1 AS $key1 => $value1) {
                $row1[$key1] = stripslashes($value1);
           } 

           $sSel = ($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant) ? 'selected = "selected"' : '';

           echo "<option value=" . nl2br( $row1['CompanyID']) . " ".sSel.">" . nl2br( $row1['Name']) . "</option>";
        } 
 ?>
```

You can also use `if`, if You want, but in other way:

```
if($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant) {
    $sSel = 'selected = "selected"';
} else {
    $sSel = '';
}
```

But I surely prefer 1st solution which I presented to You.

Answer (score 0):

Your `If` is wrong. Use this:

```
   echo "<option value=" . nl2br( $row1['CompanyID']) . " ";
   if($row['CompanyID'] == $Merchant){ echo 'selected = "selected"'};
   echo ">" . nl2br( $row1['Name']) . "</option>";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: thank you but it still gives Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @karmacat At wich line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
echo 'something ' . ( true ? 'statement is true' : 'statement is false') . ' continue echo';
```

Answer (score 0):

All the mistakes are removed.

Corrected Code:

```
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `CompanyID`, `Name` FROM `company`") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    foreach ($row1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        $CompanyID = stripslashes($value1);
        $CompanyID = nl2br($CompanyID);
        $selected  = ($CompanyID == $Merchant) ? 'selected = "selected"' : '';

        echo '<option value="' . nl2br( $CompanyID) . '"' . $selected . '></option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: returned same result 5 times in the drop down list

Comment: plus does not return the names cause its missing, plus it selects the wrong name